How can I level my basement slab and the adjacent footing for flooring?
Most of the raised floor I can see runs across several walls of my basement. It's slightly varying in height at a few points but I would say it probably averages around 1/4" or slightly more or slightly less in certain places.
Can I fill this uneven area with something that will level it? Do I have to frame over it even if the outside wall (walkout basement) is already framed and ready to go?
That is the walk out basement wall framed, insulated and wrapped in plastic barrier.    I will probably have carpet along that wall.  Yes it will be Dry walled.



What are we looking at in the pic?  Why the plastic on the wall?  Will that wall not be finished?  If it does need to be finished, the floor edge will be covered.  A pic farther away giving context would help out here.

What are your plans? How you resolve it depends on what comes next. Please revise your post to add that information.

Are you planning to put some other kind of flooring here?  Are you planning to put up drywall?

I have revised it to answer some of the questions.
